# In Typescript how to fix Cannot set property 'first' of undefined

Tags: interface, typescript

I'm trying to set a the sub property `first` that is defined in the `Name` interface but when do so I always get an error for example:

```
interface Name{
    first: string,
    last:string,
}

class Person{

    private name:Name

    public setName(firstName, lastName){
        this.name.first = firstName;
        this.name.last = lastName;
    }

}


var person1  = new Person();
person1.setName('Tracy','Herrera');
```

When running it i get the error: `Cannot set property 'first' of undefined`

Any one have an idea to work this out?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Class properties are not automatically initialized on instantiation. You need to initialize them with the corresponding objects manually -- in this case, with an object containing the properties defined by its interface:

```
class Person {
    private name: Name;

    public setName(firstName, lastName) {
        this.name = {
            first: firstName,
            last: lastName
        };
    }
}
```

---

Another approach -- for example, in case there are multiple methods setting properties on the same object -- is to first initialize the property to an empty object, preferably in the constructor:

```
class Person {
    private name: Name;

    constructor() {
        this.name = {};
    }

    public setName(firstName, lastName) {
        this.name.first = firstName;
        this.name.last = lastName;
    }

    public setFirstName(firstName) {
        this.name.first = firstName;
    }
}
```

However, with the current setup this will yield a compile error when assigning `{}` to `this.name`, because the `Name` interface *requires* the presence of a `first` and a `last` property on the object. To overcome this error, one might resort to defining *optional* properties on an interface:

```
interface Name {
    first?: string;
    last?: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but the problem with this is that I have a very huge object and doing it that way make it not readable its easy when its just two. any suggestions?

Comment: this is great, but this will work fine when you have a single level object, but when the object is so deep like `var info = {name:{first:"someName", last:"someLastName"}}` I need to init each level like `info.name = {}` and then assign `first` and `last`

Comment: I set this at ngOnInit() this.newEmployee = {
  id: 0,
  firstName: '',
  middleName: '',
  lastName : '',
  phoneNumber : '',
  emailAddress : '',
  dateOfBirth : new Date(),
  level: 0,
  imgPath: ''
};
and it works fine , where EmployeeData is typescript interface  , thank you

Answer (score 6):

You need to set **name** to an object of type **Name** (i.e. a shape matching that interface).

For example:

```
this.name = {
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Doe'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to have freedom, to make changes, separately you can do something like, using `?`,

```
interface Name{
    first?: string;
    last? : string;
}

class Person{

    private name:Name

        public setName(firstName: string, lastName: string){
            this.name = { first: firstName, last: lastName };
        }

        public setNameSample(firstName: string){
            this.name = { first: firstName };
        }

        public setNameSample1(lastName: string){
            this.name = { last: lastName };
        }
}
```

In the above case if you do not use `?` you would get something like in `setNameSample` for example if you need set only `first` :

> Type '{ first: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Name'. Property
>   'last' is missing in

Note: I think the previous answer are the way to go, this is just an added.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this

```
interface Name{
    first: string,
    last:string,
}

class Person{

    private name = {} as Name;

    public setName(firstName, lastName){
        this.name.first = firstName;
        this.name.last = lastName;
    }

}


var person1  = new Person();
person1.setName('Tracy','Herrera');
```