# Create Object and add Values in Typescript Cannot set property 'X' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hello I have a small problem to understand Typescript and how to create a Object with properties.

I dont't understand how I can create a Object and after creation add some values in it.

I read many blogs with possible solutions but nothing worked. All I get is "Cannot set property 'bookTitle' of undefined".

I already tried this solutions.
[TypeScript and field initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142071/typescript-and-field-initializers)

[How can I create an object based on an interface file definition in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142635/how-can-i-create-an-object-based-on-an-interface-file-definition-in-typescript)

[In Typescript how to fix Cannot set property 'first' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196284/in-typescript-how-to-fix-cannot-set-property-first-of-undefined)

At least I know that I have not fully understand how Typescript works and how I should fix it. It is a little bit frustrating to learn this language. I have only experience in Java...

My example code

```
//one ts file
 export interface Book {
   bookTitle: string;
   currentStatus: string;
   daysLeft: number;
   preregistrationStatus: string;
   returnDate: string;
   signature: string;
 }

 export class Lib {
   books: Array<Book>;

 ionViewDidLoad(): void {
  this.getBorrowedBooks();
 }

 getBorrowedBooks(): void {
  this.api.get('library/borrowedbooks')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      for ( let _i: number = 0; _i < data.length; _i++) {
        this.metaInfo.set( data[_i].bookTitle, data[_i].daysLeft);
       var book: Book = {
        bookTitle: data[_i].bookTitle,
        currentStatus: data[_i].bookTitle,
        daysLeft: data[_i].bookTitle,
        preregistrationStatus: data[_i].bookTitle,
        returnDate: data[_i].bookTitle,
        signature: data[_i].bookTitle,
      };
     this.books.push(book);
  }
 }
```

//Edit

Response Body

```
[
  {
    "bookTitle": "Mobile computing / Fuchß, Thomas , 2009 ",
    "returnDate": "2018-03-04",
    "currentStatus": "2. Verlängerung ",
    "signature": "2009 A 3032;h",
    "daysLeft": 21,
    "preregistrationStatus": ""
  }
 ]
```

Comment: There's a typo --> `export inteface`

Comment: This has to do with the response from `library/borrowedbooks`. Do you have an example of the response?

Comment: sry for typo -> typo fixed
and i added my Response Body

Comment: Your code looks like it should be working.  Are you able to log the value of `data[_i]` at the beginning of each iteration of the `for` loop and verify that `data[_i]` is the value you expect?  The error message seems to indicate that `data[_i]` might be `undefined` in one of the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the property. Change:

```
books: Array<Book>;
```

to:

```
books: Array<Book> = [];
```

> I have only experience in Java...

Look back and remember that you had to read up on the language to learn it. TypeScript is no different and a good book would help you immensely.